# Add a whitespace at the end of the line in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have this [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) code:

```
p
    | Avatar hosted by
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

The problem is, it's rendered to

```
<p>Avatar hosted by<a href="http://www.gravatar.com/" target="_blank">Gravatar</a></p>
```

Which looks like: "Avatar hosted by[Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/)".

No matter how many spaces I added at the end of the text line, it still looks like this. The Docs couldn't help me, and I can't imagine this to be such an uncommon problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you don't want inline HTML or HTML entities in your code this is what you can do:

```
p
    | Avatar hosted by
    =  ' '
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

or this is is shorter

```
p= 'Avatar hosted by '
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

The cleanest is probably this

```
p Avatar hosted by #{''}
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

Answer (score 39):

Which version of jade are you using?  I just tested (with 0.25.0) with a single space following 'by', and it worked correctly.

Other options are:

```
p
    | Avatar hosted by&nbsp;
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

or

```
p
    | Avatar hosted by
    |  <a href='http://www.gravatar.com/' target='_blank'>Gravatar</a>
```

Comment: Looks like I didn't add the version constraint in the `package.json`.

Comment: It's nice to know recent versions don't strip all whitespace and newlines from the end of text blocks.

Comment: it may not strip, but your editor may.  It would be nice if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 18):

Jade now supports interpolation of inline tags.

```
p this is #[strong test] of how jade will treat #[i #[u inline tags]]... like #[a(href="/") anchor tags] and #[+a() mixins].
```

http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure it's not your editor?  I use Komodo and it was set to strip trailing whitespace on save.  It was stripping the space at the end of my text line when I saved the file.  The lack of a space between my text and links was driving me nuts until I figured that out.  I changed Komodo's settings (Preferences->Editor->Save Options) to uncheck strip trailing white space, and the problem went away.

Comment: This was my problem also. In Web Storm to disable this go to preferences and search for trailing. On the bottom of the page, under Other there is an option "Strip trailing spaces on Save".

Answer (score 2):

I use the `space` variable at new line. This:

```
p
    | You must follow
    =space
    a(href=default_url) this link
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**
As jmar777 pointed out, recent versions of jade should honor trailing whitespace [see here](https://github.com/jadejs/jade-parser/blob/28d0aaa8bd8d48115fbfb7a8b28d5be2fb5c2e03/index.js#L783).  That's awesome, and I may try jade again on future projects.

**edit:**
Updated link to jade parser. [Original link](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/blob/b771df53706c6a9835c3b16c5e212194a30638fa/lib/parser.js#L536) was for jade 1.11.

Comment: `| a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar` will output as is (not as <a href...)

Comment: @RolandBertolom I'm not sure down-voting a question that is two years old because the framework has changed is the right way to handle maintaining consistent historical data. Why not suggest an edit or comment that it has changed? You can see that the accepted answer to this question is exactly the same as mine... obviously Jade has changed.

Comment: @lfender6445 thanks. I've updated with current version of jade-parser and retained the original link to jade 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and clean solution is to use this syntax:

```
p
    | Avatar hosted by
    | 
    a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

Note the space after `|` on the second text line. This will add a blank space after the previous line's text (and also spit out a nasty error if you forget to add it!).

So far this is the cleanest option, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Harp, and the [solution with two pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666280/1178021) by Óscar Gómez throws an error, although it looks very elegant.

Thanks to Даниил Пронин and Sean Gravener, I found these solutions working for me:

```
#{' '}
```

```
!{' '}
```

and

```
= " "
```

```
p
  | Avatar hosted by #{' '}
  a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

and

```
p
  | Avatar hosted by
  = ' '
  a(href='http://www.gravatar.com/', target='_blank') Gravatar
```

Also, if you're having kind of a reverse situation:
    span text #{ ref + [' '] }

Here's more on syntax interpolation in Pug (Jade):
https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html